# how to make scrollable tabbar in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, tabbar

How to make scrollable tabbar ios swift

As per my knowledge we can use maximum tab in ios. other will comes under more button.. but i want to make scrollable tabbar. so if i get 10 element in my json response its automatically create 10 items tabbar. inshort i want to create scrollable tabbar based on my json response..i found one third party library but it was in objective c.

Let me know if there is any library in swift.

Comment: https://github.com/valitovaza/scrollableTabbar Check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use collection view as a horizontal and get data from api and set based on response.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest as you can use collection view in place of a Tab Bar
. In that you can add number of cells as per response from JSON, this will work same as what you want.